# Get all results from that day of Datetime

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to be able to get all the results from a MySql database that have the same day as a certain DateTime.

For example if the DateTime's date is "2/5/2018 10:15pm" all MySql results who's DateTime day is the 5th and in the same month and year (Ignoring the time) are returned.

I tried using

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE timestamp=:timestamp, Array(':timestamp' => $targetTime)
```

But that only gives results with the exact same DateTime without ignoring the time.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE date( timestamp)=date(:timestamp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `>=` and `<` so it will preserve the index if you have.

```
WHERE timestamp >= DATE(:timestamp) 
      AND timestamp < DATE(:timestamp) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

`DATE()` will strip the time.

Here's a [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5565690/3).

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try ?

```
 SELECT * FROM posts WHERE DATE(timestamp) = DATE($targetTime);
```